# Random Exploration in Array c programming

Tags: c

I have created an array full of letters and I'm stuck on implementing the function for the cell to randomly move in one of 8 directions (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). I've used a switch statement for the basic 4 direction but couldn't figure out the other 4 directions.

```
void randomStep()
{
    if ((island[ro][co + 1] != ('B'||'L') || co == NUMROWS - 1 )&& (island[ro + 1][co] != ('B'||'L') || ro == NUMCOLS -1) && (island[ro - 1][co] != ('B'||'L') || ro == 0)
        && (island[ro][co - 1] != ('B'||'L') || co == 0))
        break;
    int direction = rand() % 8;
    switch (direction) {
    case 0: if (co < NUMROWS - 1 && island[ro][co + 1] == 'B'||'L'){  //move right
            co++;
            break;
        }
    case 1: if (ro < NUMCOLS -1 && island[co + 1][ro] == 'B'||'L') {  //move down
            ro++;
            break;
        }
    case 2: if (ro > 0 && island[ro - 1][co] == 'B'||'L'){  //move up
            ro--;
            break;
        }
    case 3: if (co > 0 && island[ro][co - 1] == 'B'||'L') { //move left
            co--;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Please, upload your code with the question, in this way we can understand what kind of problem you are facing.

Comment: `island[ro][co + 1] == 'B'||'L'` doesn't do what you think it does. You have to write `island[ro][co + 1] == 'B' || island[ro][co + 1] == 'L'`

Comment: To move in a diagonal, you increment or decrement both the row and column variables. E.g. `NE` is `ro--; co++;`

Comment: `island[ro][co + 1] != ('B'||'L')` is also wrong. The value of `('B'||'L')` is just `1`, so this is equivalent to `island[ro][co + 1] != 1`

Comment: It should be `island[ro][co + 1] != 'B' && island[ro][co + 1] != 'L'`

Comment: Instead of putting the `island[ro][co + 1] == 'B'||'L'` in each `case`, you could just put that around the entire `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine the conditions and results of two other cases. Here is an example for NW (left and up)

```
case 4: if (ro > 0 && co > 0 && island[ro - 1][co - 1] == 'B'||'L') { //move up & left
            ro--;
            co--;
        }
        break;
```

Note that I have moved the position of the `break;` to be *outside* the `if` code block.

I think you may also have an error with

```
... island[ro - 1][co - 1] == 'B'||'L' ...
```

which I guess should be

```
... island[ro - 1][co - 1] == 'B' || island[ro - 1][co - 1] == 'L' ...
```

and similarly in the other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I wanted the random walk to terminate when it steps on a cell which isn't B or L how would I implement it to the current cell?

Comment: You only need to test that once, after the move. The first `break` in your code is misplaced as there is nothing to `break` from at that point. As @Barmar wrote you can use something like `if(island[ro][co] != 'B' && island[ro][co] != 'L') { return -1; }` if the function was of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move parts of your code into functions:

```
bool mayGoUp(int ro, int co)
{
    return ro > 0;
}

bool mayGoDown(int ro, int co)
{
    return ro < NUMROWS - 1;
}

bool mayGoLeft(int ro, int co)
{
    return co > 0;
}

bool mayGoRight(int ro, int co)
{
    return co < NUMCOLS - 1;
}
```

Note: I changed the logic a bit: from `co < NUMROWS - 1` to `co < NUMCOLS - 1`; not sure which one is the correct one.

Then you can combine them in a straightforward way:

```
bool mayGoUpLeft(int ro, int co)
{
    return mayGoUp(ro, co) && mayGoLeft(ro, co);
}
```

Then, using them in your code will make your code clearer:

```
    switch (direction) {
    case 0:
        if (MayGoRight(ro, co) && island[ro][co + 1] == ...
        {  //move right
            co++;
            break;
        }
...
    case 99:
        if (MayGoUpRight(ro, co) && ...
        {  // move up and right
            ro--;
            co++;
            break;
        }
```